# Chrome CSS Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a search box and button which was working in all browsers (Chrome, FF, IE7/8/9, Opera) a few weeks ago, but now is incorrectly offset a bit in Chrome only.

Here it is in Chrome
[image]

And here it is in Opera, FF, IE
[image]

Notice the slight offset in Chrome. Here is the HTML For this search box,

```
<form id="function_search_form" method="post" class="span-24 textcenter last">
    <input type="text" name="basic_search_input" id="basic_search_input" />
    <input type="image" src="images/magnifying_glass.png" name="basic_search_button" id="basic_search_button" alt="Search Blueprints" />&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <a id="switch_adv_search" style="cursor: pointer; color: #1C94C4; font-size: 15px;">advanced</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_type" value="basic" />
    <div id="autocomplete_choices" class="autocomplete"></div>
</form>
```

And here is the CSS for these elements,

```
#function_search_form #basic_search_button {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 25px;
    width: 27px;
    margin: 0.5em 0px;
    padding: 1px 0px;
}

#function_search_form #basic_search_input {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    color: #050;
    font: bold 12px 'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I have tried to wrap the inputs in a div, and use absolute position or relative position. However everything I change breaks it in some other browser but fixes it in Chrome. It seems to be also that if I take vertical-align out of the text input that fixes it in Chrome.

I am not sure if this is a new bug that was introduced in the latest version of Chrome or not, but I remember this working in Chrome before and nothing has changed with it since.

**UPDATE FOR STEVE CAMPBELL's SOLUTION**

I am not sure how yours is working, because if I take out everything except my CSS file and this HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="function_search_form" method="post" class="span-24 textcenter last">
        <input type="text" name="basic_search_input" id="basic_search_input" />
        <input type="image" src="images/magnifying_glass.png" name="basic_search_button" id="basic_search_button" alt="Search Blueprints" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a id="switch_adv_search" style="cursor: pointer; color: #1C94C4; font-size: 15px;">advanced</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="search_type" value="basic" />
        <div id="autocomplete_choices" class="autocomplete"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like the following,

[image]

Only thing I can think is that Fiddle has some different reset or something.

Comment: A 1px discrepancy? Do you have a JSFiddle or other live example we can poke around at?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas No sorry. Its on a private password protected application. Cant really show it all. What else are you looking for? I can try and give a little more CSS and HTML if you want but im not sure how much it will help.

Comment: Did you normalize the CSS? Different browsers tend to have different defaults for some properties. It's usually a good idea to reset them.

Comment: @Tom I would LOVE to have a reset on here (it may have fixed this issue), and if it was up to me there would have been. However at this point adding a reset would jack up our entire application and its not something we have the time to add.

Comment: If you aren't able to add a reset for the entire application it might not be a bad idea to take a look at a popular css reset (like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)) and pull out the parts for the forms and apply it just to your style for these elements.

Comment: @Mat I guess the problem is that some other elements probably look good just because the CSS was NOT reset. Fixing some of it might break other parts. But it's still worth a try.

Comment: @Tom Thats right.....I will see what I can do with your suggestion though Mat.

Comment: @Tom I TAKE THAT BACK. We are loading in Blueprint CSS which has a reset in it. It is also possible that Blueprint is what is jacking this up.

Answer (score 2):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RMLY/) works ok for me.  Styled using relative and absolute, and tweaking box-sizing to ensure consistency across browsers, and removed the margin that was in em:

```
#function_search_form
{
    position: relative;
}
#function_search_form #basic_search_button {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: 25px;
    width: 27px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 250px;
}

#function_search_form #basic_search_input {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
    color: #050;
    font: bold 12px 'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;    
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;    
}

#function_search_form a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;    
    left: 280px;
}
```

Comment: I did try some absolute positioning with these elements, but whenever I do that it seems to work in Chrome, FF, IE9, but breaks in IE7/8 which I cant have. Your particular CSS is all messed up for me. May have something to do with things in Fiddle being different, or things on my side being different.

Comment: I just realized we actually are using Blueprint which has a reset in it. Maybe if you add that to the fiddle it may change what you have.